# Is there any software to show ssd usage details so far?

Tags: ssd

I have an SSD in my laptop.

Is there any freeware software that will show how much data I have written and read since I have been using this disk?

The SSD I am using is Kingston HyperX.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide name of your SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this toolbox (for sandforce controllers) to look for amount of written data - http://www.kingston.com/us/support/technical/downloads?product=SV300S3&filename=SSD_Toolbox_20

P.S. Provide full name of your SSD. There is difference in SSD controllers and software.